# Finding value that does not match while using SumProduct formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the following formula I sum up values in a column, I like to expand this so that it discounts values, if a value in another column ends with a "*D".

So far I have got it so that it sum only those that end in a "*D".

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($DY$16,ROW($DY$16:$DY$273)-ROW($DY$16),,1)),--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*D",$EB$16:$EB$273)))
```

Question 1: How to reverse the formula to exclude value "*D"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--ISNUMBER` part of your formula evaluates `TRUE` whenever the "D" is located

Changing this part to `-ISERROR` will evaluate `TRUE` whenever the "D" is **not** located

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IFERROR(SEARCH("D",CategoryRange),"-")<>LEN(CategoryRange))*SumRange)
```

should work if there is only on D.
CategoryRange is the range of cells in Category code column and SumRange is the range of cells in column to be summed over

It works for me. `IFERROR(SEARCH("D",CategoryRange),"-")` finds the position of 'D' in the Categore Code column, if it is not equal to `LEN(CategoryRange)` then the 'D' is not at the end, which creates a boolean array that you want.  Please check it stepwise with "Evaluate Formula" in excel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((IFERROR(SEARCH("D",$EB$16:$EB$273),"-")<>LEN($EB$16:$EB$273))*$DY$16:$DY$273)

Comment: Afraid it didn't work for me, summed up every row in the column included the one with "D" at the end

Comment: I hope you did not use "*D" in this formula